# How to upload files with .db file format from a remote server to a local server?

Tags: c#, json, sftp, file-transfer

I am trying to create an SFTP C# application. This application will download files from a remote directory to a local server which in this case my laptop. I have managed to get some functions working but since I am C# newbie with couple of months of experience, there are lots of things I still don't know. This is the application [interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS5lh.png)

The application basically, read the data from a JSON file that has all the information to connect to the SFTP server, this is how I read and deserialized the JSON file.

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
var currentList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Datalogger>>(text);
```

below is an example of my JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "Record": 1,
    "IPaddress": "192.168.6.247",
    "Machinename": "taurus",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "sourcefolder": "/home/root/conf",
    "destfolder": "C:/Users/Sami/Desktop/DB Files/",
    "filextension": "db",
    "removedownloaded": 0
  },
  {
    "Record": 2,
    "IPaddress": "192.168.2.255",
    "Machinename": "taurus",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "sourcefolder": "/home/root/conf",
    "destfolder": "C:/Users/Sami/Desktop/DB Files/",
    "filextension": "json",
    "removedownloaded": 1
  },
  {
    "Record": 3,
    "IPaddress": "192.168.4.255",
    "Machinename": "taurus",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "sourcefolder": "/home/root/conf",
    "destfolder": "C:/Users/Sami/Desktop/DB Files/",
    "filextension": "db-journal",
    "removedownloaded": 1
  }
]
```

I have tried this implementation below, it is perfectly working on files with .JSON, and .txt, but when I switch to a directory with .db  files, it doesn't seem to work or download anything with (.db).

This is how I extract the value from the JSON  file:

```
string host = currentList[0].IPaddress;
string username = currentList[0].username;
string password = currentList[0].password;
string remoteDirectory = currentList[0].sourcefolder;
string localDirectory = currentList[0].destfolder;

using (SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
            {
                try
                {
                    sftp.Connect();
                    Console.WriteLine("Machine 1 - Connected");
                    var files = sftp.ListDirectory(remoteDirectory);

                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string remoteFileName = file.Name;
                            //if ((file.Name.EndsWith(".db")))

                                using (Stream file1 = File.OpenWrite(localDirectory + remoteFileName))
                                {

                                //if (!file.IsDirectory && !file.IsSymbolicLink)

                                sftp.DownloadFile(path: remoteDirectory + remoteFileName, output: file1);


                                }

                            sftp.Disconnect();
                        }
```

Any thoughts on how to download .db files to my local server.

Comment: "when I switch to a directory with .db files, it doesn't seem to work or download anything" This isn't very informative. What actually happens when you run it on a directory with .db files? Does it get the filenames? Does it try to download the files? does it produce any error messages? What do the errors say?

Comment: In my remote server, there are multiple folders, each with different files. So far, I can only download files with.JSON and .TXT, however, when I change my filePath to a folder with .db files, I can see that the files are not being transferred to my local machine. ERROR1: An exception has been caught System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported. ERROR2: Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in mscorlib.dll, the same error is generated even for json and txt file but they are successfully downloaded.